# setuptools: installing pytorch from download link: 403 Forbidden

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi, pytorch

I am trying to include pytorch in the requirements list for setuptools:

```
install_requires=[
      'torch'
      ],
dependency_links=[
      'http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl' '@develop#egg=torch'
      ],
```

But after running `python setup.py develop` I receive:

```
error: Can't download http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl@develop#egg=torch: 403 Forbidden
```

I also tried using the source install link rather than the one for pip:

```
install_requires=[
      'torch'
      ],
  dependency_links=[
      'https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source' '@develop#egg=torch'
      ],
```

But then:

```
RuntimeError: PyTorch does not currently provide packages for PyPI (see status at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566).
```

What is the correct way to install pytorch through setuptools? (Note: using anaconda is not an option in my case)

Thank you.

**EDIT**:

As suggested in the answer, I also tried:

```
dependency_links=[
      'https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch'
      ],


dependency_links=[
      'https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#egg=torch'
      ],


dependency_links=[
      'http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl'
      ],
```

And received:

```
RuntimeError: PyTorch does not currently provide packages for PyPI (see status at https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/566).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error: if you use direct URL to a wheel file:

```
http://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-0.3.0.post4-cp27-cp27mu-linux_x86_64.whl
```

You must not use `@develop#egg=torch`. That part is for installing from VCS like git.

The second URL

```
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch#from-source
```

is also wrong. It should be

```
https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch
```

and here `@develop#egg=torch` is exactly right if you want to install `develop` branch.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both versions give me the same error. Is it impossible to install torch with setuptools?